# Sql Query Not Work Properly

Tags: sql, vb6, ms-access-2007

I have a **Amount Subtract** application in which a User have **multiple amount**

when a particular user want **deduct** his/her amount he give his/her name then amount

**For Exapmle**(Visual Basic 6.0 specific application)

```
**Name**-----------------------------------**Amount**

John--------------------------------------200

John---------------------------------------200

John---------------------------------------200
```

If John Want to Reduce his amount he give 100 Rupes then The Result Which should be Come is

```
**Name**-----------------------------------**Amount**

John--------------------------------------100

John---------------------------------------200

John---------------------------------------200
```

But My Program Shows

```
**Name**-----------------------------------**Amount**

John--------------------------------------100

John---------------------------------------100

John---------------------------------------100
```

*Here is my Program Code*

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()

Dim temp,liab,v,nc As Integer
Dim result As Variant
Dim con As New ADODB.Connection
Dim RST As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim sSQL As String

con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" _
     & App.Path & "\Customer.mdb;Persist Security Info=False"

sSQL = "Select * From Table1 Where Name ='" & Text1.Text & "'"
RST.Open sSQL, con, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
liab = CInt(Text3.Text)

Do Until RST.EOF
temp = CInt(RST("Amount").Value)
v = temp - liab
If v < 0 Then
RST("Amount") = 0
RST.Update
RST.MoveNext
nc = CInt(RST("Amount").Value)
RST("Amount").Value = nc + v
RST.Update
Exit Sub

Else
RST("Amount") = v
RST.Update
End If
RST.MoveNext
Loop
RST.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: your code selects ALL records with the name JOHN and loops thru them all to deduct 100.  its doing exactly what you wrote.  you need a more unique identifier than a name

Comment: Can you suggest any idea because once I think Id which have primary key but a person have many records and primary key is auto increment

Comment: What is the primary key in the table? Please don't tell me it's the person's name. Also, how do you specify which account they want the amount deducted from? If "John" has 3 accounts, how do you know it's the first account to deduct 100 from? You need to reference the primary key (if you even have one) which could be `Account_No`, or something along those lines?

Comment: @MarkLaREZZA my program works fine on different amount value its only create problem when the amount is same else my program capable of deduct amount...

Comment: *"...only create problem when the amount is same..."* Really? What do you get in your example when user withdraws a) `199`; b) `200`; c) `201`? Can you see a pattern now?